# Resize and merge images vertically

Tags: imagemagick

How to resize images (width = average of the width of all images) and merge them vertically from top-to-bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `imergv.py` script, in Python, that does just that. Imagemagick is required.
Note that before running the script, you need to `cd` into the directory with the images. Some image viewers suited to view large images are Viewnior, Nomacs and Gwenview. The script will generate some `tmpfXXXX.png` images and a file called `output.png` with the end result.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

f = os.popen('/bin/ls -1')
fil = f.read()
arfils = fil.split("\n")
arfils.pop()
num = 0
tot = 0

for snc in arfils:
f = os.popen( "/usr/bin/identify -ping -format '%w %h' " + '\"' + snc + '\"' )
    rslt = f.read()
    woh = rslt.split(" ")
    intvl = int(woh[0])
    tot = tot + intvl
    num = num + 1

avg = tot // num

#resize images
num = 1
allfil = ""
for snc in arfils:
    nout = "tmpf" + str(num).zfill(4) + ".png"
    allfil = allfil + nout + " "
    convcmd = "convert " + '\"' + snc + '\"' + " -resize " + str(avg) + " -quality 100 "
    convcmd = convcmd + '\"' + nout + '\"'
    #print convcmd
    f = os.popen(convcmd)
    num = num + 1

mrg = "convert -append " + allfil + "output.png"
f = os.popen(mrg)
```